# Should Google be considered as the ultimate resource for checking sentences?

Tags: discussion

As I did before and based on the suggestions, I do google to find matches for the sentences/phrases I'm doubtful about. Some times, although sentences seem to be correct, there are no (or few) matches  for them. For example, for "is disagreeable at first glance", there is one exact match in the Google Books.
So, my straight question is should I rely on such results?

Comment: We have special place for questions like this, which are about how to use the site, rather than how to English: [meta]. We'll move this question there so we can discuss it. The short answer is *no*, Google is not the ultimate authority. There are better ones. But the important thing you're doing, or have learned to do, is research your doubts for yourself, *first*, before asking others to help you. That's so great and so rare. Now you have a great method for deciding whether to ask about a phrase here: if you looked in Google Books and didn't get many hits, ask away!

Comment: (Having said that, please do bear in mind that the likelihood of finding a specific string of words decreases *exponentially* in tree number of words used. That's the power of language!)

Comment: "There are better ones", Can you let me know some of them?

Comment: @You could use [COCA, for example](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), and search for ***is** [adjective] **at first glance***. Or just search Google Books for the less restrictive string ***disagreeable at first glance***, and ignore any false matches where ***disagreeable*** is the last word of a preceding sentence. Personally I don't think "disagreeableness" is a very good match to vision-based metaphoric "glance" (particularly with the copula ***is***; it might work a little better with ***seems***). But that's personal preference/semantics, nothing to do with grammatical "correctness".

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers, COCA is a good alternative.

Comment: Native speakers say sentences every day that no one's ever said before.  You'll never find any of them in a Google search, but that doesn't mean there's anything wrong with them.

Comment: @snailboat, Definitely you're right, however searching could be used for finding common and general structures.

Comment: Yes, you can use corpus evidence if you add in a good dose of *thought*.  But it is in no sense reliable on its own; it does not "check" sentences.

Comment: @snailboat, Agreed!